# Recover lost files after commit and rollback in Mercurial. (Equivalent of git reflog?)

Tags: mercurial

Commited work. Did a rollback when I wasn't on the tip of the repo. Lost files. Looking for git reflog equivalent to save my work.

Long:
So I finish work, then commit.

```
$ hg commit -A
[...]
adding media/js/fbfriends.js
removing media/js/streams.js
adding media/js/templetizer.js
[...]
$ hg log
$ hg log
changeset:   10:ce3ad416d9a5
tag:         tip
user:        Mihai
date:        Sat Sep 10 22:34:35 2011 -0700
summary:     Save all.

changeset:   9:ceacb7b2192a
user:        Mihai
date:        Sat Sep 10 22:25:34 2011 -0700
summary:     Mootools update.
[...]
```

Some browsing:

```
$ hg checkout 8
```

Okay. Then I wanted to change revision 10. Stupidly, I do:

```
$ hg rollback
rolling back to revision 9 (undo commit)
$ hg status
[...]
M media/js/mootools.js
R media/js/streams.js
! media/js/fbfriends.js
! media/js/templetizer.js
[...]
```

WTF? Where did my two files go????

```
$ hg log
changeset:   9:ceacb7b2192a
tag:         tip
user:        Mihai
date:        Sat Sep 10 22:25:34 2011 -0700
summary:     Mootools update.
[...]
```

Okay, i'll figure out the .orig files:

```
$ hg revert --all
[...]
undeleting media/js/streams.js
forgetting media/js/templetizer.js
reverting media/js/mootools.js
[...] // media/js/fbfriends.js doesn't even show up
$ hg status
? media/js/mootools.js.orig
$ hg history
changeset:   9:ceacb7b2192a
tag:         tip
user:        Mihai
date:        Sat Sep 10 22:25:34 2011 -0700
summary:     Mootools update.
```

NOOOOOO! I've been royally fscked for being on commit 8 when i did the rollback.
Recovery attempts fail:

```
$ hg checkout 10
8 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ find -name temp
$ hg checkout 9
30 files updated, 0 files merged, 63 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ find -name temp
$ hg checkout ce3ad416d9a5
abort: unknown revision 'ce3ad416d9a5'!
$ hg checkout ceacb7b2192a
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ find -name temp
$
```

But, but.. I pushed it in! It should still be somewhere in .hg? Help?
`git reflog`, `git checkout blah` saved me in a couple instances but are there any mercurial equivalents?

EDIT: Made summary clear.
EDIT2: Better title.

Comment: I don't know why people aren't commenting/answering here on SO, but there is some discussion on reddit which may help you: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/kc6lx/mercurial_cant_help_you_recover_your_work_like/

Comment: So it's years later, I'm hunting around various git/mercurial articles, and I find this.  I also find out that 2.0 onward now comes with a safety on the trigger.  You can still do the unsafe behavior you describe but only with "--force".  Rollback doesn't mean "in our minds let's go back in time", it means "I'm gonna carve it out with a knife."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, they are gone.

The help summary for the `rollback` command is:

```
roll back the last transaction (dangerous)
```

and goes on to say:

```
This command should be used with care. There is only one level of
rollback, and there is no way to undo a rollback. It will also restore the
dirstate at the time of the last transaction, losing any dirstate changes
since that time. This command does not alter the working directory.
```

Rollback is the *only* non-extension mercurial command that removes history, and there's been talk about moving it to a disabled-by-default extension like it's similarly destructive cousins `strip` and `purge`.

Not that it helps you now, but in the future clone before doing a rollback.  Or better yet do a `backout` instead.  Backout adds the inverse of a change, yielding the same resulting tip revision, but with a more accurate history ("I did this", "I undid it").